# how to add form validation rule in this script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, validation

hello i've learned about codeigniter form validation and i see on this [tutorial](http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-crud-modal-server-side-validation.html) script form validation like this

```
private function _validate(){

        $data  = array();
        $data['error_string'] = array();
        $data['inputerror'] = array();
        $data['status'] = TRUE;

        if($this->input->post('post_nama') == ''){
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'post_nama';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Nama harus diisi';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        } 

        if($this->input->post('post_jk') == ''){
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'post_jk';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Jenis Kelamin harus diisi';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        } 

        if($this->input->post('post_alamat') == ''){
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'post_alamat';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Alamat harus diisi';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        } 

        if($data['status'] === FALSE){
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

my question is, if i want to use limited_number or max_length in that script, where i can place it?

Comment: why the client-side tags?

Comment: @Rizki: it is better to use  jquery validator plugin for front end validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if( validation ){
        $data['inputerror'][] = '';
        $data['error_string'][] = '';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }
```

Add youself validation

Comment: can you explain it to me, if i want to use in post_nama

Comment: Use regular to match the maximum or minimum  if ( regular  ) {}